# python asyncio asynchronously fetch data by key from a dict when the key becomes available

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Like title told, my use case is like this:

I have one aiohttp server, which accept request from client, when i have the request i generate one unique request id for it, and then i send the `{req_id: req_pyaload}` dict to some workers (the worker is not in python thus running in another process), when the workers complete the work, i get back the response and put them in a result dict like this: `{req_id_1: res_1, req_id_2: res_2}`.

Then I want my aiohttp server handler to `await` on above `result dict`, so when the specific response become available (by req_id) it can send it back.

I build below example code to try to simulate the process, but got stuck in implementing the coroutine `async def fetch_correct_res(req_id)` which should **asynchronously/unblockly** fetch the correct response by `req_id`.

```py
import random
import asyncio
import shortuuid

n_tests = 1000

idxs = list(range(n_tests))

req_ids = []
for _ in range(n_tests):
    req_ids.append(shortuuid.uuid())

res_dict = {}

async def fetch_correct_res(req_id):
    pass

async def handler(req):
    res = await fetch_correct_res(req)
    assert req == res, "the correct res for the req should exactly be the req itself."
    print("got correct res for req: {}".format(req))

async def randomly_put_res_to_res_dict():
    for _ in range(n_tests):
        random_idx = random.choice(idxs)
        await asyncio.sleep(random_idx / 1000)
        res_dict[req_ids[random_idx]] = req_ids[random_idx]
        print("req: {} is back".format(req_ids[random_idx]))
```

So:

1. Is it possible to make this solution work? how?
2. If above solution is not possible, what should be the correct solution for this use case with asyncio?

Many thanks.

---

The only approach i can think of for now to make this work is: pre-created some `asyncio.Queue` with pre-assigned id, then for each incoming request assign one queue to it, so the handler just `await` on this queue, when the response come back i put it into this pre-assigned queue only, after the request fulfilled, i collect back the queue to use it for next incoming request. Not very elegant, but will solve the problem.

Comment: see also [async_dict](https://github.com/milahu/async_dict)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if the below sample implementation fulfils your need

basically you want to respond back to the request(id) with your response(unable to predict the order) in an asynchronous way

So at the time of request handling, populate the dict with `{request_id: {'event':<async.Event>, 'result': <result>}}` and `await` on `asyncio.Event.wait()`, once the response is received, signal the event with `asyncio.Event.set()` which will release the await and then fetch the response from the dict based on the request id

I modified your code slightly to pre-populate the dict with request id and put the `await` on `asyncio.Event.wait()` until the signal comes from the response

```
import random
import asyncio
import shortuuid

n_tests = 10

idxs = list(range(n_tests))

req_ids = []
for _ in range(n_tests):
    req_ids.append(shortuuid.uuid())

res_dict = {}

async def fetch_correct_res(req_id, event):
  await event.wait()
  res = res_dict[req_id]['result']
  return res

async def handler(req, loop):
      print("incoming request id: {}".format(req))
      event = asyncio.Event()
      data = {req :{}}
      res_dict.update(data)
      res_dict[req]['event']=event
      res_dict[req]['result']='pending'
      res = await fetch_correct_res(req, event)
      assert req == res, "the correct res for the req should exactly be the req itself."
      print("got correct res for req: {}".format(req))

async def randomly_put_res_to_res_dict():
    random.shuffle(req_ids)
    for i in req_ids:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(2,4))
        print("req: {} is back".format(i))
        if res_dict.get(i) is not None:
          event = res_dict[i]['event']
          res_dict[i]['result'] = i
          event.set()  

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = asyncio.gather(handler(req_ids[0], loop),
          handler(req_ids[1], loop),
          handler(req_ids[2], loop),
          handler(req_ids[3], loop),
          randomly_put_res_to_res_dict())
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
loop.close()
```

sample response from the above code

```
incoming request id: NDhvBPqMiRbteFD5WqiLFE
incoming request id: fpmk8yC3iQcgHAJBKqe2zh
incoming request id: M7eX7qeVQfWCCBnP4FbRtK
incoming request id: v2hAfcCEhRPUDUjCabk45N
req: VeyvAEX7YGgRZDHqa2UGYc is back
req: M7eX7qeVQfWCCBnP4FbRtK is back
got correct res for req: M7eX7qeVQfWCCBnP4FbRtK
req: pVvYoyAzvK8VYaHfrFA9SB is back
req: soP8NDxeQKYjgeT7pa3wtG is back
req: j3rcg5Lp59pQXuvdjCAyZe is back
req: NDhvBPqMiRbteFD5WqiLFE is back
got correct res for req: NDhvBPqMiRbteFD5WqiLFE
req: v2hAfcCEhRPUDUjCabk45N is back
got correct res for req: v2hAfcCEhRPUDUjCabk45N
req: porzHqMqV8SAuttteHRwNL is back
req: trVVqZrUpsW3tfjQajJfb7 is back
req: fpmk8yC3iQcgHAJBKqe2zh is back
got correct res for req: fpmk8yC3iQcgHAJBKqe2zh
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work (note: I removed UUID in order to know req id in advance)

```
import random
import asyncio

n_tests = 1000

idxs = list(range(n_tests))

req_ids = []
for i in range(n_tests):
    req_ids.append(i)

res_dict = {}

async def fetch_correct_res(req_id):
    while not res_dict.get(req_id):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    return req_ids[req_id]

async def handler(req):
    print("fetching req: ", req)
    res = await fetch_correct_res(req)
    assert req == res, "the correct res for the req should exactly be the req itself."
    print("got correct res for req: {}".format(req))

async def randomly_put_res_to_res_dict(future):
    for i in range(n_tests):
        res_dict[req_ids[i]] = req_ids[i]
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print("req: {} is back".format(req_ids[i]))

    future.set_result("done")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.Future()
asyncio.ensure_future(randomly_put_res_to_res_dict(future))
loop.run_until_complete(handler(10))
loop.close()
```

Is it the best solution? according to me No, basically its kind of requesting long running job status, and you should have (REST) api for doing the job submission and knowing job status like:

```
http POST server:port/job
{some job json paylod}
Response: 200 OK {"req_id": 1}

http GET server:port/job/1
Response: 200 OK {"req_id": 1, "status": "in process"}

http GET server:port/job/1
Response: 200 OK {"req_id": 1, "status": "done", "result":{}}
```